# Continuity of Neumann eigenvalues over smooth approximated domains

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Let $\mu_k(\Omega)$ be the $k$-th Neumann eigenvalue on a piecewise smooth and bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, $k \geq 2$. Assume also, for simplicity, that $\Omega$ has only a finite number of nonregular points, and each of such points corresponds to a right inward corner, e.g., as on the figure below.

Let $\Omega_\varepsilon$, $\varepsilon>0$, be a sequence of *smooth* domains which approximate $\Omega$ from the inside. That is, $\Omega_\varepsilon$ rounds the corners of $\Omega$ in some "good" way, see again the figure. (The requirement that $\Omega_\varepsilon \subset \Omega$ is not essential, in principle.)

[image]

> I'm looking for some results about the convergence
>   $$
> \mu_k(\Omega_\varepsilon) \to \mu_k(\Omega) \quad \text{as}~ \varepsilon \to 0,
> $$
>   for appropriately chosen approximations $\Omega_\varepsilon$.

The problem is that the smoothing of corners is not a smooth perturbation of $\Omega$, and hence the required convergence is not apriori clear. (Recall that we are in the Neumann case).